# Prevent network card going into low power mode

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, dell, intel-wireless

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS 15. The network adapter is:

> Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)

Every 15 - 20 minutes my WiFi is disconnecting. If I am doing a ping, then the ping will just freeze. It will not say network unavailable or anything, it will just freeze until I disconnect and re-connect the network or reboot.

At exactly the time of freezing (I verified this by doing a continuous ping with timestamp), this appears in the syslog:

> Dec  7 08:57:21 mark-XPS-15-9530 kernel: [  565.390598] wlp6s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by
>   02:18:4a:a6:18:b1

It appears that my network card is going into power saving mode or something.

**Update** here are my network system details: https://gist.github.com/LondonAppDev/9cb52ed8b2a6e26c00946708d8c33a33

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205

Comment: Cheers @M.Becerra, I ran the script suggested and updated the question.